# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have rails app which are working perfectly in the local computer. But when I'm deploying it on Heroku I get next error in the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hollow-cloud-nnn.herokuapp.com/stylesheets/application.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hollow-cloud-nnn.herokuapp.com/javascripts/application.js
```

I have this files in the app\assets\javascript and \app\assets\stylesheets folder.

Here is my config\production.rb:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Here is console output of deployment:

```
       Using mongoid (2.4.7)
       Using rails (3.2.1)
       Using sass (3.1.15)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
       Using uglifier (1.2.3)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compiled slug size is 15.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v24
       http://hollow-cloud-7412.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:hollow-cloud-7412.git
   cb8ded3..dc103ac  master -> master
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should [precompile assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) or set `config.assets.compile = true` in your production environment.

More information is available on heroku dev center, read [how to use rails 3.1+ asset pipeline on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar).

Comment: I was trying to fix it, but didn't have success. I have updated my question to give more information.

Comment: Is it correct, that rails search files in the '...herokuapp.com/stylesheets/application.css' folder? (The 'public' folder is missing.

Comment: did you try to restart app? during live compilation it will generate files in `/public/assets` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are a mongoid user running rails 3.1+ . This is quite a common issue for Mongoid users as the documentation instruct you to remove this line in `config/application.rb`

```
require 'rails/all'
```

To resolve this, add the following line to `config/application.rb`

```
require 'sprocket/railtie'
```